# In React Native how can I access the native camera app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I would like to add a link to my app that opens the phone's native camera app? Is this possible?

I'm aware that react-native-camera exists but from the docs it seems like it only supports accessing the camera for the purpose of creating your own camera interface inside your app. I would rather just use the camera app already on the phone.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker), you can access phone native's camera.

[EDIT]
An example Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   View,
   Image,
   Button
} from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker";
export default class App extends Component {
   state = {
   pickedImage: null
   }
   reset = () => {
      this.setState({
         pickedImage: null
      });
   }
   pickImageHandler = () => {
      ImagePicker.showImagePicker({title: "Pick an Image",
      maxWidth: 800, maxHeight: 600}, res => {
         if (res.didCancel) {
            console.log("User cancelled!");
         } else if (res.error) {
            console.log("Error", res.error);
         } else {
            this.setState({
               pickedImage: { uri: res.uri }
            });
         }
      });
   }
   resetHandler = () =>{
      this.reset();
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <View style={styles.container}>
             <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Pick Image From Camera and Gallery</Text>
             <View style={styles.placeholder}>
                <Image source={this.state.pickedImage} style={styles.previewImage} />
             </View>
             <View style={styles.button}>

                <Button title="Pick Image" onPress={this.pickImageHandler} />

                <Button title="Reset" onPress={this.resetHandler} />

            </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
        alignItems:"center"
     },
     textStyle: {
        fontWeight:"bold",
        fontSize:30,
        textAlign:"center",
        color:"red",
        marginTop:10
     },
     placeholder: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "black",
        backgroundColor: "#eee",
        width: "70%",
        height: 280,
        marginTop:50,
     },
     button: {
       width: "80%",
       marginTop:20,
       flexDirection:"row",
       justifyContent: "space-around"
     },
     previewImage: {
       width: "100%",
       height: "100%"
     }
  });
}
```

Source: [react-native-image-picker](https://c1ctech.com/react-native-image-picker-example/)

Comment: Can you include the essential parts please? Such as API methods - links will not always be there.

Comment: @JRK sorry for the late reply I added the code as you said

Comment: Does this code open the Camera in RN? Seems that it opens that gallery? The OP asked for the Camera.

Comment: @JRK yes the code can open both camera and gallery, he can choose whatever he want. I am running the same code in my app

Comment: Thanks man! and I thought Opening native camera in android will not be possible in this life.

Comment: Issue with this library : It stores two images for every image capture from camera.